# How to remove specific text after the pipe sign in rdlc expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have an expression in rdlc textbox that contains values like this

```
STRU|CBR
```

Now I want to remove the text after pipe sign | and also the pipe sign if there's one. But if there's no pipe sign then the actual data should be returned.

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
Right( Fields!Code.value, len(Fields!Code.value) - 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
=IIf(Fields!Code.value.IndexOf("|") = -1, Fields!Code.value, Fields!Code.value.Substring(0, Len(Fields!Code.value) - Fields!Code.value.IndexOf("|") - 1 ))
```